# Pandas using map or apply to make a new column from adjustments using a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data from a sporting event and the knowledge is that there is a bias at each home arena that I want to make adjustments for. I have already created a dictionary where the arena is the key and the value is the adjustment I want to make.

So for each row, I want to take the home team, get the adjustment, and then subtract that from the distance column. I have the following code but I cannot seem to get it working.

```
#Making the dictionary, this is working properly
teams = df.home_team.unique().tolist()
adj_shot_dict = {}
for team in teams:
    df_temp = df[df.home_team == team]
    average = round(df_temp.event_distance.mean(),2)
    adj_shot_dict[team] = average

def make_adjustment(df):
    team = df.home_team
    distance = df.event_distance
    adj_dist = distance - adj_shot_dict[team]
    return adj_dist

df['adj_dist'] = df['event_distance'].apply(make_adjustment)
```

Comment: Hello, please update your question to include a minimal example of the DataFrame in question. I believe the problem can be solved using only `df`.

Comment: I'm not sure what a minimum example of the DF would look like, there are ~90,000 rows and all of them are needed to get the mean. The home_team column is a string of the home team identifier and the distance is just a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you already have the dict and you want simply subtract `adj_shot_dict` to `event_distance` column:

```
df['adj_dist'] = df['event_distance'] - df['home_team'].map(adj_shot_dict)
```

---

**Old answer**

Group by `home_team`, compute the average of `event_distance` then subtract the result to `event_distance`:

```
df['adj_dist'] = df['event_distance'] \
                 - df.groupby('home_team')['event_distance'] \
                     .transform('mean').round(2)

# OR

df['adj_dist'] = df.groupby('home_team')['event_distance'] \
                   .apply(lambda x: x - x.mean().round(2))
```

**Performance**

```
>>> len(df)
60000

>>> df.sample(5)
  home_team  event_distance
5     team3              60
4     team2              50
1     team2              20
1     team2              20
0     team1              10
```

```
def loop():
    teams = df.home_team.unique().tolist()
    adj_shot_dict = {}
    for team in teams:
        df_temp = df[df.home_team == team]
        average = round(df_temp.event_distance.mean(),2)
        adj_shot_dict[team] = average

def loop2():
    df.groupby('home_team')['event_distance'].transform('mean').round(2)
```

```
>>> %timeit loop()
13.5 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit loop2()
3.62 ms ± 167 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Total process
>>> %timeit df['event_distance'] - df.groupby('home_team')['event_distance'].transform('mean').round(2)
3.7 ms ± 21.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: so there's no way to do this with apply or map? seems process-intensive to find the average for every single row. I know it would only add a couple of seconds if that but doesn't seem... proper yano?

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, for every single row, your method is grouping all the events that have the home team, finding the mean, and then subtracting it.  It seems wasteful to calculate that every single time when I already have a dictionary with that calculation. Does that make sense?

Comment: Build and fill your dict is time consuming because you iterate x time over your dataframe (x is the number of your `home_team`). The groupby / transform is fast.

Comment: Right, so I only iterate 30 times to get all the calculations instead of finding the calculations (in this case) 70,000 times. Unless I'm miss understanding how python executes all this.

Comment: I apologize, I'm probably explaining this poorly. The creation of the dictionary only happens once. (I'm actually using it for something else, I just included the code in case I was somehow creating it incorrectly) 

Since I already have that, I use use the hometeam column as the key, and subtract from the event distance the value in the dictionary. So it shouldn't be 70,000 X 30

Comment: Ok. IIUC, you already have the dict with adjustments and you want to subtract to the `event_distance` column?

Comment: Correct, so each home team will subtract by a different amount, thus the key-value pairs.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it's what you want now (I hope).

Comment: Yea, that is what I was looking for. Thank you for your patience!